# How to Query search index on cloudant using java?

Tags: java, gwt, full-text-search, cloudant

I am newbie for cloudant and trying to learn full text search on cloudant through tutorial video. I am successful in searching on the cloudant.com through http request ,Now I want that code to be in java as i am working on GWT framework with java. Till now , I am just able to create connection with cloudant.com by studying the particular github project [GITHUBLINK](https://github.com/cloudant/java-cloudant#creating-a-view-map-reduce-index)

There its given for search like this

```
Search search = db.search("views101/animals");
SearchResult<Animal> rslt = search
                               .limit(10)
                               .includeDocs(true)
                               .counts(new String[] {"class","diet"})
                               .querySearchResult("l*", Animal.class);
```

**My Questions:**

*1. what exactly is this `Animal.class` refer to?*

*2. If this not the way what are the steps for full text search on cloudant.*

I have created the view and the search index manually on cloudant.com under a designdoc of a database.

Answer (score 2):

`Animal.class` refers to the class that the documents found will be deserialised into, if you do not have a class to deserialise the data into, you should be able to a `HashMap` or similar class to access the data returned.

Comment: Thanks for mentioning HashMap if don't want to serialize into a full class

Answer (score 0):

You can find the example source code for the Animal class in this location: https://github.com/cloudant/java-cloudant/blob/88202a1bd7b9b04d96c4b7b8498a1b8f7f99c9e5/src/test/java/com/cloudant/tests/Animal.java.

Like the previous answer indicated, you could also have the results returned as a generic JsonObject that provides access to the properties and values.